# What should the Rehm-Weller equation look like?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrons, photochemistry, fluorescence

The Rehm-Weller equation, which defines the energy change for photoinduced electron transfer according to Lakowicz "Principles of Fluorescence Spectroscopy" [1, p. 337] should look like:

$$\Delta G=E^\mathrm{red}(D^+/D)-E^\mathrm{red}(A/A^-)-\Delta G_{00} - \frac{e^2}{\epsilon d} \tag{1}$$

So you can see the first two components are reduction potentials of donor $D^+$ and acceptor $A$. But sometimes you can find another definition:

$$\Delta G=E^\mathrm{ox}(D/D^+)-E^\mathrm{red}(A/A^-)-\Delta G_{00} - \dfrac{e^2}{\epsilon d} \tag{2}$$

Which one is correct? I'm totally confused.

#### References

1. Lakowicz, J. R. Principles of Fluorescence Spectroscopy, 3rd ed.; *Springer: New York*, **2006**. ISBN 978-0-387-31278-1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both expressions are identical. It's just juggling of the signs, since

$$E^{\mathrm{red}}(D^{\cdot+}/D) = - E^{\mathrm{ox}}(D/D^{\cdot+})$$

Relevant primary references would be:

- Rehm, D.; Weller, A. H. *Isr. J. Chem.* **1970**, *8*, 259-271.
- Rehm, D.; Weller, A. H. *Ber. Bunsen-Ges. Phys. Chem.* **1969**, *73*,
  834-839.
- Weller, A. H. *Z. Phys. Chem. NF* **1982**, *133*, 93-98.

A normative glossary of terms in photochemistry is available from the [IUPAC](http://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/2007/pdf/7903x0293.pdf).

Comment: Actually, both expressions are then not identical. There is a minus sign missing in the second one.

Comment: @tschoppi exactly. I was surprised when I saw that. It looks that some researchers does not understand something or what it is more likely, that I do not understand something.

Answer (score 5):

By convention both donor (D) and acceptor (A) potentials are listed as reduction potentials. For a nice description, see Turro's explanation of the Rehm-Weller equation in his photochemical treatise "Modern Molecular Photochemistry of Organic Molecules"

To clarify, the equation that is being referenced is not actually the Rehm-Weller equation but is the "Gibbs free energy of photoinduced electron transfer".

Please refer to the IUPAC definition of [Gibb's energy of photoinduced electron transfer](http://goldbook.iupac.org/GT07388.html).

The Gibbs energy of photoinduced electron transfer is part of the Rehm-Weller equation. The Rehm-Weller equation is the correlation between second order rate constants and Gibbs energy of photoinduced electron transfer.

See the IUPAC definition of the [Rehm-Weller equation](http://goldbook.iupac.org/RT07472.html)